# Tried many ways to root my Telenor Infinity E

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, selinux

I have been trying to root my phone for two weeks using various exploits but till now all in vain. The devices isn't international so its not famous and I couldn't find any recovery, custom root or rooting method for it on the internat, although I found stock ROM which saved my phone several times when I soft bricked it.

**My Device:**

```
Model: Telenor Infinity E
Build: TELENOR_INFINITY-E_L100
AOS: version 6 Marshmallow
RAM: 1 GB 
Chipset: MediaTek MT6735M
Kernel: 3.18.19 Aug 22, 2016
Android Security Patch level: July 5, 2016
Stock recovery: Having no menu
```

Bootloader: Unlocked

**Methods Tried:**

1. Tried famous desktop applications: OneClickRoot, KingRoot, KingoRoot, RootGenius, iRoot etc. (All failed)
2. Tried flashing TWRP of similar device using SP Flash tool. (Result: Boot Loop)
3. Tried porting TWRP recovery using stock recovery and Android Kitchen. (Result: Auto reverted back or Soft Bricked)
4. Tried injecting su, supersu in system.img using android kitchen and flashed. (Result: Soft Bricked)
5. Tried Many Repack tools like simg2img/make_ext4 binaries, similar tools/guides to repack system.img. (Result: Soft Bricked)
6. Modified ro.secure=0 and ro.adb.secure=0 in default.prop and re-flashed boot.img (success, but no root)
7. Used dirtycow exploit scripts got root shell but still no permissions to modify /system.
8. Patched adbd in boot.img using adb insecure app's assets and got 'adb root' access. (still can't modify /system or remount in rw)
9. Found SELinux's getenforce=1 and neither could disable it by command setenfore=0 or echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce nor found any method except making a custom build of kernel (which is not feasible for me).

Can someone help me to Root this device or tell me if there is anything else I can try?